# Spherical coordinates and unregular paraboloid

Tags: calculus, integration

If we have the following equation of a paraboloid:
$z=4-x^2-y^2$ and we have the region in space bounded by this paraboloid from above and by the $xy$-plane from below; we want to find the volume of this region using the spherical coordinates in the following orders; $d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$,
$d\phi\,d\rho\,d\theta$.

In the first order if we follow a ray from the origin, it will cut the surface which is the one of the paraboloid but we will end up with a second degree polynomial equation...

Comment: I forgot to mention, that it’s the limits that we need to find

Comment: why you want use spherical coordinates?

Comment: Because it was required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:

$$x^2+y^2=4-z$$

we obtain:

$$\rho^2 \sin^2\phi=4-\rho \cos \phi\implies\rho^2 \sin^2\phi+\rho \cos \phi-4=0$$

and thus

$$\rho=\frac{-cos \phi\pm \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi+16\sin^2 \phi}}{2\sin^2 \phi}\implies \rho=\frac{-cos \phi+ \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi+16\sin^2 \phi}}{2\sin^2 \phi}>0$$

> $$
> \iiint \; dV = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac{-cos \phi+ \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi+16\sin^2 \phi}}{2\sin^2 \phi}}\rho^2 \sin \phi \; d\rho d \phi d \theta
> $$

Comment: Ohh so I wished I’ve done that.... but when $\phi$ is zero then $sin\phi$$=0$ then we cannot find $\rho\$ in that case... but when $\phi\=0$ we know that $z=4$ we can get the value of $\rho\$ in that case but we cannot get it from the original equation

Comment: @DanielKamand when you evaluate for $\phi\to 0$ $$\rho=\frac{-cos \phi+ \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi+16\sin^2 \phi}}{2\sin^2 \phi}\to 4$$

Comment: Oh you took the limit... I forgot that $\phi$ represents a cone... so it is irrelevant to have have it equal 0 right?

Comment: @DanielKamand I think taht is not essential for th calculation of the limit. As an alternative you cold simplify the expression by multiplying numeretor and denominator by $$+cos \phi+ \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi+16\sin^2 \phi}$$ In this way you should eliminate the problem for $\phi=0$.

Comment: That’s true because it’s too complicated, but they  told to set up the limits only without evaluation,